# jquery error using form input name array format: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm using jquery Guardian form validate in my project and I have problem when using [] in my input name. I need get input value with array because my form add dynamically more input from an input.This sample code of my form this is:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="myform">

<input type="text" name="firstname[]" id="firstname_1" required="required" data-empty-message="error"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

This Part of jquery code has problem:

```
 createErrorMessage:function(el) {
       var name = el.attr('name'),
        val = el.val(),

        form = this.$el.attr('id'),

        errorMessage = el.data('error-message'),

        emptyMessage = el.data('empty-message');       

        //error message is only created once

        //error message is only created if a error message is available 

        if(!$('#error-message-'+form+'-'+name).length) {

            if(errorMessage || emptyMessage) { 

                el.after('<span class="ui-error-message" id="error-message-'+form+'-'+name+'"></span>'); 

            }

        }



        if(!val.length && emptyMessage) {



            $('#error-message-'+form+'-'+name).html(emptyMessage);

        } else {

            $('#error-message-'+form+'-'+name).html(errorMessage);

        }

    }
```

I checked console and my error this is:
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #error-message-myform-firstname[]
When delete [] from input name it's work but I need add [] to input name.
What is my problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Why have you added []? Are there multiple fields with same name?

Comment: If you need the `[]` so badly, use another `data-` attribute like `data-name` and set its value without the `[]`. And things will work. This will keep name of your element with `[]` and will also make those error element function

Comment: In my form dynamically add more input from an input and need use [] to get all firstname in php array